# data field type for decimal does not work as required

Tags: php, mysql

I have field where i store my grand total to a mysql filed as total and its type set as `decimal(10,2)`

When my php form adds up and updates the query for `112381348.40` (i.e 112 million)

but when i fetch or view it on phpMyadmin, the value shows as `99999999.99`

from my data type set, it has to be `10 digits` and `2 decimals` where as it is maximum updating as `8` and `2`.

Am i understanding wrong or what am i doing wrong.

I know i can increase it to `decimal(13,2)` and then see it.

But i would like to know the reason, why `10,2` is not happening?

Comment: As an aside - it's probably also worth wrapping any floating point numbers written to the database inside a `number_format()` function if your site is multi-lingual otherwise a locale like 'nl_NL' will throw a spanner in the works by using `,` as the decimal point separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specification for `decimal(m, n)` takes two arguments.  The first is the "precision" and the second is the "scale".  More colloquially, the first is the number of digits in the number.  The second is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

So, your specification of `decimal(10, 2)` can store numbers like:  12,345,678.90 -- i.e., up to 99,999,999.99.  And that is the maximum number.

If you want to store numbers larger than that, then use a larger precision for the number.  For your number, you need at least `decimal(11, 2)`, although I would suggest a larger precision so you don't encounter this problem in the future.

Comment: ok, now i got it, i was getting confused with mysql documentation on their site, so even for simple maths, i could minus the first 11 by 2 which is 9... and 2 is for fractional digits and 9 would be integer digits. I think, its very clear now for me, thank you and accepting your answer for nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In setting a float or decimal field, the first int value is the total character count. The second is how many decimal places. So:

```
//decimal(10,2)
12345678.90

//decimal(13,2)
12345678901.23

//decimal(7,3)
1234.567
```

See?

Comment: Unless you're using a really old version of MySQL which did it wrong.

Comment: @CD001, no. am using the latest mysql version. thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 0):

You have 11 digits. The first number is the total digits. Try:

```
DECIMAL(11, 2)
```